# Expo apple sign in doesnt work in production

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to implement apple sign in in my expo managed project and the sign in doesnt work in production. I have followed all the documentations steps. Changed the bundle ID to the right one.

```
const handleAppleRegister = (dispatch) => async () => {
  try {
    // await firebase.auth().signOut() // sign out first
    const nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);

    return await Crypto.digestStringAsync(Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256, nonce)
      .then((hashedNonce) =>
        AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
          requestedScopes: [AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME, AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL],
          nonce: hashedNonce
        })
      )
      .then((appleCredential) => {
        const { identityToken } = appleCredential;
        const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
        provider.addScope('email');
        provider.addScope('name');
        provider.addScope('displayName');
        provider.addScope('photoURL');

        const credential = provider.credential({
          idToken: identityToken,
          rawNonce: nonce
        });

        return Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(async resp => {
          console.log(resp)
          const currentUserUID = resp.user.uid;
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          db.collection('users').doc(currentUserUID).set({
            email: resp.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            uid: resp.user.uid,
          });
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('status', 'apple');
          dispatch({ type: 'handleAppleRegister', payload: 'apple' });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // ...
        console.error(error);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 'ERR_CANCELED') {
      // handle that the user canceled the sign-in flow
    } else {
      // handle other errors
    }
  }
};
```

I've searched every where for a solution but with no luck. Anyone knows what is missing here

Comment: did you find any solution?